# Cant get the proper use for DropDownListFor with a model and a viewbag element

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a list of locations set in the `ViewBag` element like this:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var db = new ErrorReportingSystemContext();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Locations
          .AsEnumerable()
          .Select(c => new SelectListItem
          {
              Value =c.id.ToString(),
              Text = c.location_name
          });
        ViewBag.locations = items;
        return View();
    }
```

I'm trying to get the values from ViewBag.locations from the view like this

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.location_fk_id, ViewBag.locations);
    //@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.location_fk_id, @ViewBag.locations);
    //@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.location_fk_id, "locations");
```

But no avail. How can i use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to cast it if you are doing it this way:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.location_fk_id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.locations)
```

Comment: This works great thank you! I wish this was the only problem i had, now i have a problem when doing an edit.